# WPF control pool

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, controls, pool

I have an `ItemsControl`, with virtualization and many rows. Each row contains the same container, though each container is different in some way. 
Example picture:

[image: RadioButtons]

This is an example with radio buttons all the way down. "Jumping" to a new scroll position (using `IsDeferredScrollingEnabled = true`) causes a "lagg" of about 1 sec. I would like to achieve reuse of the controls. In this particular case I would want a pool consisting of radio buttons allready used (and detached).
Each time the user navigates, the pool should be checked first.
Is this possible? And how?

If not: Is there any faster way of creating such pages with huge amounts of controls?

Comment: If you already have virtualization going, just let IsDeferredScrollingEnabled to false and it should be fast, at least in your image, it don't have too many parts to bring the app to a halt while scrolling.

Comment: Turning it off causes a lagging behavior when jumping far down(which is a usage of my control, where users could jump to specific elements)

Comment: Can you post an example project? I tried to replicate here and didn't gave lags, my last apps even has a more complex UI and was running fine. Also, can you check if the virtualization is actualy working using snoop (visual studio 2015 already has the live tree to see how many elements are visible)?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Tried to create a testproject and everything were smooth. Was using a custom Control to enable smooth virtualized scrolling which caused a drawback to performance. Though I would still like a pool of controls to gather from

Comment: Yeah, smooth scrolling is hard when you need to visualize, is one of the things i'm trying to achieve in WPF too.

Comment: http://blog.devart.com/wpf-smooth-scrolling-with-ui-virtualization.html
-This works pretty well. All you gotta do is to decrease the amount of calculations it`s doing.